# efficiently arranging paintings on walls

Tags: optimization, autocad

For my work in a big depot of a museum I need to arrange thousands of paintings on galery walls. I have a list of paintings and their size. Additionally each painting is assigned to a group (like century or style). Paintings of a similar group should be positioned on the wall close to each other.
I was given the hint that autocad could help me, however searching the internet I could not find a starting point.
Therefore I wanted to ask:

- what functionality or methods of autocad can help me? Can you give me a starting point?
- Do you know any other tool, that fits better the task?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! We are programmers, but your question, in it's current form, has nothing to do with programming. You are asking us for help with autoCAD. So, I'm sorry to say that this question should be closed.

Comment: Besides, if you want to arrange thousands of paintings, you'll need some serious computational power. Your laptop won't be able to do it in a reasonable amount of time, neither will some beast of a gaming rig. These are **heavy** calculations as there is an infinite amount of ways to hang the paintings.

Comment: You are touching some serious computational problems with this question, [Optimization problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem) and [Packing problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem). I don't know `AutoCAD` and if it may be appropriate to give you a satisfying solution. Whatever, it's more complex than you might think.

Comment: I can guarantee you that AutoCAD does not handle this type of problem.  It would allow you to draw a nice layout of where things go (after you've figured it out).

Comment: Hire a very good curator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if my question wasn't the right one for this blog. I know, I'm not actually programming, I work in museums and I just needed some suggestions how Cad may help me at my work.  Now I know, it is not the right program to reach such goals :-). I sincerely thank you all for the kind answers!